# Remove RAID5 hardraid

Tags: raid

I have Proxmox installed on a server with 3x300GB drives with soyoustart (OVH hosting company).

I am unable to figure out how to remove the hard raid so that I can have the lvm volume with raid 0

```
fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 557.9 GiB, 599013720064 bytes, 1169948672 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf4f37666

Device     Boot    Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        4096   40962047   40957952  19.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       40962048   43057151    2095104  1023M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3       43057152 1169940479 1126883328 537.3G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       43059200 1169940479 1126881280 537.3G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/pve-data: 533.3 GiB, 572665102336 bytes, 1118486528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

--

```
df
Filesystem           1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                  16409832       0  16409832   0% /dev
tmpfs                  3285292   13400   3271892   1% /run
/dev/sda1             20026236 1937852  17064436  11% /
tmpfs                 16426444   24960  16401484   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                 16426444       0  16426444   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/pve-data 550336720   71452 522303108   1% /var/lib/vz
/dev/fuse                30720      16     30704   1% /etc/pve
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hardware RAID. You can't do it from your Linux shell (unless you have some special utility provided by SoYouStart).

On a classic server, you would reboot it, go to your RAID-controller BIOS setup, break the RAID-5 configuration into three separate JBOD (independent) disks. Of course that would render your present system completely unusable.

With a hosted server, you would need a KVM IP to have access to the early boot stages, and later you would need a way to reinstall your OS. But anyway, SoYouStart won't probably let you fiddle with the RAID-controller BIOS.